# Edit and Filtering Issues in Custom Cell Templates in UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using custom cell template whose field is bind to a function expression. Cell data is bind with an Object which have multiple Keys. I am using a custom function which return a string to that column cell template.

Now there are 2 issues which i am facing after doing this implementation.

1. Filtering is not working for that particular cell.
2. There is an angular error while moving to edit mode for that cell:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'row.entity'getDisplayTitle'' is non-assignable. Element: 'getDisplayTitle'" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope">

I have replicated this issue using plunker.

[Plunker - UiGrid](http://plnkr.co/edit/4VoGyU73aNMruso2dNeQ)

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.getDisplayTitle = function (rowEntity, column) {
            var displayTitle = "";
            if (rowEntity[column] !== null) {
                if (rowEntity[column].length > 1) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < rowEntity[column].length; i++) {
                        displayTitle = displayTitle + rowEntity[column][i].street + "; ";
                    }
                }
                else if (rowEntity[column].length == 1) {
                    displayTitle = rowEntity[column][0].street;
                }
                else
                    displayTitle = rowEntity[column].street;
            }
            else {
                displayTitle = "";
            }
            return displayTitle;
        }
    $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering:true,
            columnDefs: [
              { name:'firstName', field: 'first-name' },
                  { 
              name:'address', 
              field: 'getDisplayTitle()', 
              cellTemplate : '<div class=".ui-grid-cell-contents"> {{grid.appScope.getDisplayTitle(row.entity, col.colDef.name)}} </div>'},

            ,
              { name:'1stFriend', field: 'friends.name' }

          ],
            data : [      {
                               "first-name": "Cox1",
                               "friends": {name:"ritesh"},
                               "address": [{street:"ritesh1", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"puneet", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"kavleen", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},]

                           },{
                               "first-name": "Cox2",
                               "friends": {name:"puneet"},
                               "address": [{street:"ritesh2", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"puneet", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"kavleen", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},]

                           },{
                               "first-name": "Cox3",
                               "friends": {name:"kavleen"},
                               "address": [{street:"ritesh3", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"puneet", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"kavleen", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},]

                           },{
                               "first-name": "Cox4",
                               "friends": {name:"alankar"},
                               "address": [{street:"ritesh4", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"puneet", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},{street:"kavleen", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},]

                           }
                       ]
          };

}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to this row:

```
field: 'getDisplayTitle()',
```

That says to the grid that the value should be found inside `rowEntity.getDisplayTitle()` [Beware, that this is not pointing to `$scope.getDisplayTitle()`, so I think it will not work as you hoped].

But as you can see, `getDisplayTitle()` is a function, and you cannot assign a value to a function:

```
getDisplayTitle() = foo; // This is not a valid expression in javascript
```

So you have to put a property of your row entity inside of `field` and you will find that value updated after the user ends editing.